# what does --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT mean in node command line?

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, port

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l55lOyerZk) video, the author uses the line `node index.js --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT`, what does `--bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT` mean?.
The example consist of dockerizing a simple node app and deploying it to heroku, in the Dockerfile file the last line says `CMD node index.js --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT`.
 The index.js file:

```
...
const port = process.env.PORT||2000;
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
...
})
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding a service to 0.0.0.0 means that your service will listen on all it's network interface. For example if you're deploying on your computer the service will be accessible from the localhost ip (127.0.0.1) and his ip inside your local network (192.168.X.X or what ever localnetwork address is))
`$PORT` reference a bash variable (for example 8080) this is the port using to acces your service.

In that case by doing this command you should be able to acces index.js from any browser that can `ping` your computer using his ip on the port `$PORT` (depend of your `$PORT` value)

Comment: Is `--bind` option part of node command line? where can I read more about it?